# Using sudo without typing sudo more than once per sudo session?

Tags: security, sudo

How can one use `sudo`, without typing `sudo` more than once per `sudo` session?

By that I mean that you'll be asked to type your password each 15 minutes after the last command you executed, while executing commands within this time (within this "grace period") will restart the timeout.

Another example:

1. You boot the system.
2. You execute any command whatsoever.
3. Immediately after that, you are being asked to fill in your password.
4. The command is executed.
5. If 15 minutes passed and you haven't typed any command (say, you suddenly had to leave the PC), you will be prompted for your password again.

This could save typing the word `sudo` instead typing it tens if not hundreds of times a day (not always you run scripts as `sudo`).

Comment: This is how sudo works by default, isn't it?

Comment: Up until this moment I thought one should type "sudo" before each command within the "grace period".

Comment: Oh, yes, I misunderstood: you still need to type "sudo" before each command. You might want to open a root shell then: `sudo -i` -- from there, each command you execute is ran as root

Comment: If it implements the grace period concept it's good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sudo -i`. The `-i` option will log you in and you won't have to retype the password or add `sudo` before commands every single time.

Comment: Is this `su` mode? Because I don't the regular `su` mode.

Comment: No, this is not `su` mode. `sudo -i` simply logs you in with your(current user's) password and gives you root privileges.